# Modify "visualization" for autonomous navigation of turtlebot

Tags: navigation, rviz, visualization, turtlebot, 2d-nav-goal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! i am using ros electric and i would like to use the navigation and visualization toolbox to implement the autonomous navigation for the turtlebot. In particular i want to reach some preset goals without the click of the mouse on the map in rviz. is it possible to modify directly the visualization stack of ROS? which are the files that rviz uses when i click on the "2d nav goal" and "2d pose estimate" buttons?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45328/modify-%22visualization%22-for-autonomous-navigation-of-turtlebot/) by [Yuri](https://answers.ros.org/users/2892/yuri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2012-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you click on the buttons *2D Nav Goal* and *2D Pose Estimate* all the *rviz* does is the publishing a simple message on the specified topic. By default those topics and messages are:

- *geometry_msgs/PoseStamped* on the topic */move_base_simple/goal* in case of *2D Nav Goal*
- *geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped* on the topic *initialpose* in case of *2D Pose Estimate*

You are free to use any other publisher to send messages to those topics and therefore control the navigation stack either from your own program or from the command line using *rostopic pub* like:

```
rostopic pub -1 /move_base_simple/goal geometry_msgs/PoseStamped '{pose: {position: {x: 1.0}}}'
```

You can see which topics are called with specified button press in the *Tools Properties* panel window, which is usually localted in the upper right corner of the *rviz*. You can use this panel as well to change the default values for topics to be called.

---

Originally posted by [Jakub](https://answers.ros.org/users/2948/jakub/) with karma: 1821 on 2012-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-10**:
Just an additional note: in your own programs, you should not publish just simple pose goals on a single topic because you cannot monitor the execution of navigation action that way. Instead, use actionlib. See http://ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals

**Comment by [Yuri](https://answers.ros.org/users/2892/yuri/) on 2012-10-31**:
thanks!!